# JavaFX Scene Builder Path Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx, ide, scenebuilder

When setting the path to the Scene Builder executable in Eclipse and after applying the changes, I am still unable to open any .fxml files in Scene Builder. My Scene Builder is installed under the AppData folder. Would this cause any issues as I see most installations are under the Oracle folder. I am able to open Scene Builder outside of Eclipse.

Path Set: C:\Users\"Username"\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder\SceneBuilder.exe

Please let me know if you require any more information. Thanks!

Comment: you can watch this video for installation details https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2j-e1CHsqsE&list=PLS1QulWo1RIaUGP446_pWLgTZPiFizEMq&index=5